# sencha touch store filter number

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, sencha-touch, store

I'm using a filter on a store to find entries with a specific number but when I filter only a single digit, the filter finds other numbers as well, if the specific digit occurs within that number.

```
store.filter('shiftNum', 1);
```

In this case the filter may find entries such as 10, 11, 12 as well, and so on.

As there are only 21 possible numbers in my store, a problem arises only when filtering numbers 1 or 2.
A quick fix may be to input only double digits eg .01, 02. But theoretically the filter should search for only the number and nothing else.
I tried changing the fields in the model to specify a number field, as apposed to "auto" or "string" but it doesn't help.

```
Ext.define('Sidur.model.Opt', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [
                {name: 'shiftNum', type: 'number'},
                {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
            ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'sqlitestorage',
                dbConfig: {
                    tablename: 'sidur'
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

(By the way the data is stored locally on WebSQL)

Answer (score 1):

Use filter mixed collectiomn or even a custom function

```
store.filter({
  property: fieldName,
  value: fieldValue,
  exactMatch: true,
  caseSensitive: true
});
var longNameFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(item) {
        return item.name.length > 4;
    }
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filterBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy)

```
store.filterBy(function(record, id) {
    return record.get('shiftNum') === 1;
});
```

Comment: thanks, in the end i used a regex, (found and modified on stackoverflow) although it doesn't make sense to me why it's needed. theoretically a filter should find exactly the number inputed, that seems like a really basic functionality. this is most efficiently achieved with the regex.
I'll definitley be using the filterBy function in the future though.
`{
            property: 'shiftNum',
            value: /^(1)$/
        }`